# get each value from select multiple

Tags: jquery

easy one guys:

i have a `select`, `type multiple`, so i need to do a loop to send to database each value **that was selected**, one by one.

this is what i have done so far, but my  `$.each` are returning `0 1 2 3`.

how can i do this ?

**html:**

```
   <select multiple="multiple" id="sel">
          <option>All</option>
          <option>Option 1</option>
          <option>Option 2</option>
          <option>Option 3</option>
  </select>
```

**js:**

```
    $("#send").click(function(){
         var sel = $("#sel").val();
         $.each(sel, function(e){
             alert(e); // should come the text of each one
         });
    });
```

Thanks.

Comment: and what do you want next, what kind of help?

Comment: my alert are returning 0 1 2 3 4 , and i need the text of each option one by one like i say

Comment: made some changes to be more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You show the `key` not the `value`. try this

```
$.each(sel, function(key,value){
             alert(value); // should come the text of each one
         });
```

Comment: funny, i did something like this, but dos not work. now is working, maybe i miss something. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I undestand well, you want to retrieve the html content of each value.

So you should do this:

```
     $.each(sel, function(index, element){
         alert(element.html());
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

e = index , not an array element itself

```
$.each(sel, function(e){
    alert(sel[e]); // should come the text of each one
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean a server-side database, the next step is to set up a server side application that can insert the rows into the database that you're sending it from jQuery.

[On the jQuery side](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) you probably want something like: `$.post(someurl, sel);`

This is based on the assumptions made in your question, but I'm not actually sure what you expect sel to contain here. You may want to look at [jQuery.serialize or serializeArray](http://api.jquery.com/?s=serialize).

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/wfqa7/3/

you need the value in the $.each, not the index. jQuery.each gives these two parameters to your callback function.